# First Home Savings Account (FHSA) in Canada

Tags: canada, rental-property, first-time-home-buyer, capital-gain, fhsa

FHSA was introduced in Canada in 2023 for first time home buyers. From what I read I can open a FHSA, because I have not lived in the house since I bought it (always rented). I can contribute up to $8,000 annually for a max of $40,000 (till 2028). I intend to wait and make the $40K deduction in 2028 against my personal tax return (T1) as this is when I will sell the rental property for a capital gain. I see this as a no brainer and will take advantage of the FHSA. Can you please confirm my understanding of this account.